# angular 2 ngbaccordion programmatically call (panelChange)

Tags: angular, bootstrap-accordion

I've got a ngbAccordion with a panelChange event that works great.  What I'm wondering is if there is a way in the ngOnInit if I can programmatically call that method?

```
<ngb-accordion #regularAccordion="ngbAccordion" *ngFor="let item of cartItems; index as i" activeIds={{activeIds}} (panelChange)="toggleAccordion($event, item)">
```

(panelChange) method I want to call :

```
toggleAccordion(event: any, item: any) {
  const accords = this.regularAccordions.toArray();      
  this.accordionStatus.set(event.panelId, event.nextState);
  if (accords.length > 1) {
    const lastItem = this.activeIds[0];
    if (this.activeIds.length > 0) {
      const currentPanel = this.activeIds.includes(event.panelId);
      if (currentPanel) {
        this.activeIds = [];
      }
    } else {
      this.activeIds = [];
      this.activeIds.push(event.panelId);
    }
    // when you select a second accordion and set status in map to true for one the other doesn't get set to false.
    this.regularAccordions.toArray().forEach(singleAccordion => {
      if (singleAccordion.activeIds.length > 0) {
        if (lastItem !== event.panelId) {
          this.accordionStatus.set(lastItem, false);
          this.activeIds = [];
          this.activeIds.push(event.panelId);
        }

      // singleAccordion.activeIds = [];
      } else {
       singleAccordion.activeIds = this.activeIds;
      }
    });
  } else {
    this.activeIds = [];
    this.activeIds = event.panelId;
  }
  this.setSelectedItem(item);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.

Have a `@ViewChild` for your `#regularAccordion` reference and then with `ngAfterViewInit` set a listener which ngb supplies you:

`@ViewChild ('regularAccordion') regularAccordion: NgbAccordion;`
(Import **NgbAccordion**)

`ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ref.panelChange
      .subscribe(panel => console.log(panel));
}`

A working sample: [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spyfjy?file=app%2Faccordion-preventchange.html)

Comment: Hey @monogate this doesn't really show how to fire the panel change method